# create a 1200px div with no page overflow

Tags: css

I have a div on page with a fixed width of 1200px. It's this way because I inserted inside a collection of thumbnails to creates a mosaic. I don't want the mosaic to change if the page is resized.

The problem is that I don't want to have horizontal scrollbars on the page. The div is placed just for visual purposes.

How can I avoid the horizontal navigator scrollbars that is automatically created when browser size is smaller than the div size?

Update: The div can't be positioned fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in css:

```
html,body {
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

or if you want vertical scrollbars, `overflow-x: hidden`

or a cleaner way:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="mosaic"></div>
</div>
```

and put `width:100%;overflow:hidden` on the wrapper.

Comment: overflow: scroll-y doesn't seem to work for this. The width:100%;overflow:hidden sample shouldn't change the position of the items inside when resizing?

Comment: sorry, that should read `overflow-x: hidden`, brain fart...  And no, `width:100%` on the wrapper won't effect anything in terms of positioning in mosaic if mosaic has a width set.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this simply by setting your div to **fixed** positioning.

```
.hugediv {
  background: blue;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say it can't be fixed because it can't get stuck get scrolled vertically.

Comment: also, fixed position doesn't work in older browsers (IE6 or earlier)